# Why does the compiler show the error "no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'carti' and 'int')"

Tags: c++

Every time I try to run my code the compiler always shows error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'carti' and 'int')| multiple times. I'm trying to read 10 structures out of a single file and assign them to the 'c[i]' variable using the 'for' loop, sort them in three different ways and then print them on-screen. (this is a school assignment)
this is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct carti{
    char nume[41];
    float pret;
    float rating;
}c;

int main(){
    int i,j;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("carti.txt");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        getline(c[i].nume,41)
        fin>>c[i].pret;
        fin>>c[i].rating;
        cout<< c[i]<<"\n";
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(c[i].nume[0]>c[i+1].nume[0]){
            c[i]=c[i+1];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<c[i]<<"\n";
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(c[i].pret>c[i+1].pret){
            c[i]=c[i+1];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<c[i]<<"\n";
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(c[i].rating>c[i+1].rating){
            c[i]=c[i+1];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<c[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable c is not an array. It is a scalar variable. So you may not apply the subscript operator.

Comment: what do you whink `c` is and what do you think `c[i]` is?

Comment: `c` is of type "carti" (that should be capitalized). What do you expect `c[i]` to do?

Comment: Avoid using raw arrays.  Use `std::vector<carti>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do this :

```
    struct carti{
        char nume[41];
        float pret;
        float rating;
    }c[10];
```

Having said this, there are other problems with your code.

Say for example, you want to do `cout<<c[i]`. To accomplish this you need to provide an overloaded operator `operator<<` which works for your struct.